# Error for if statement with grep

Tags: r

Running the following code:

```
if(grep("sales", resume$jobs$title, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = FALSE, value = FALSE,
     fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE, invert = FALSE)) {p2_feature = 1}
else if(grep("\\$[0-9]+",resume$jobs$text,ignore.case = TRUE, perl = FALSE, value = FALSE,
             fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE, invert = FALSE)){p2_feature = 1}
else {p2_feature = 0}
```

Getting an Error:

> Error in if (grep("sales", resume$jobs$title, ignore.case = TRUE, perl
>   = FALSE,  :    argument is of length zero

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

You must be thinking of `grepl`, not `grep`.  `grepl` returns a vector of logical values.  `grep` just returns the indices of `TRUE` values (which is of length 0 if there are none).  Just replace `grep` with `grepl` and you should be fine.

Comment: Got it Thanks. I used Length(grep) > 0